# Switched version of jQuery and now get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, typeerror

I moved this working code into WordPress and from

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

to WordPress's embedded version jQuery v1.12.4

and now I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

```
<div class="meter">
  <span style="width:50%"></span>
  <p></p>
</div>

var bar = $('span');
var p = $('p');

var width = bar.attr('style');
width = width.replace('width:', '');
width = width.substr(0, width.length-1);


var interval;
var start = 0; 
var end = parseInt(width);
var current = start;

var countUp = function() {
  current++;
  p.html(current + '% completed);

  if (current === end) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
};

interval = setInterval(countUp, (1000 / (end + 1)));
```

What am I missing with the version change?

Comment: The replace function in this code is running fine for me. Could there be more than one span on your HTML page? Maybe specify an ID for the span and then get the width for the span with this specific ID. https://jsfiddle.net/ts7hj8ks/1/

Answer (score 0):

@TheShaman has hit upon the reason for the error.  It's not the upgrade of jQuery but the introduction of another `span` that is causing the problem.  If an earlier `span` being picked up by your selector lacks a `style` attribute, you will get the error message you're reporting.  Simply make your selector more restrictive to correct the problem:

```
var bar = $('.meter span');
```

Comment: I considered that beforehand and tried adding .meter span I also tried adding a class to the span tag. It still dies at the .replace.